# GDALOpen: "ERROR 1: Too Big for Int" is informative only?

Tags: gdal

When I use GDALOpen to open an ESRI Imaging .img file I see the error: 
"ERROR 1: Too Big for Int"
Is this an actual error, or a warning? I see no way to avoid the message, It is puzzling since I am only opening the file, not trying to read from it. I seem to be able to read the file properly anyway. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Are you sure it is an `ESRI' Imaging file? Never heard of them before.

Comment: What version of GDAL are you using (as well as 32 or 64 bit)? Are you on a 32 or 64 bit operating system?

Comment: Add the report from `gdalinfo image.img -hist`.

Comment: GDAL Version: gdal.x86_64 1.11.4-3.el7, 64-bit system working in C++

Comment: I don't know how to  Add the report from gdalinfo image.img -hist. I cannot issue GDAL commands in my current environment. I am set up to compile and run C++ programs that link with GDAL libraries.